# Haskell: Instance for data multiple type variables?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I want to create a type class for various types of "columns of stuff", so something like this:

```
class Column c where
     at :: c a -> Int -> a

data ListColumn a = ListColumn {
     lcContent :: [a]
}

instance Column ListColumn where
  at c i = lcContent c !! i
```

Now I want to derive one column from another. Say I have a column of customers, and I want to derive a column of customer names from that. So I wrote:

```
data DerivedColumn a b c = DerivedColumn {
    dcBase   :: c a, 
    dcDerive :: a -> b
}
```

`a` being the customer, `b` the customer name in the example above. Now I thought I could write something like this:

```
instance Column (DerivedColumn a b) where
    at c i = dcDerive c $ at (dcBase c) i
```

But ghc does not seem to like it (`Column should have kind * -> *, but DerivedColumn a b has kind (* -> *) -> *`). Can someone please point in the right direction...?

Comment: It’s a little bit unclear to me what exactly you want, but it looks like maybe you need to shuffle the type variables from `DerivedColumn` to have the container type, `a`, last? So the definition should be `data DerivedColumn c b a = ...`? The `Column` typeclass expects a type that it can apply a container type to in order to get a concrete type.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want instead is this:

```
data DerivedColumn c a b = DerivedColumn {
    dcBase   :: c a, 
    dcDerive :: a -> b
}

instance Column c => Column (DerivedColumn c a) where
    at dc i = dcDerive $ at (dcBase dc) i
```

To expand a bit, if you look at your `Column` class, you'll see that `c` has kind `* -> *`, and the `a` in `c a` is the type of the values that `c` contains. I assume that the value of the columns that `DerivedColumn a b c` contains should have type `b`, so it should really be the last value you pass to the type constructor for you to define an instance of `Column`.

Comment: I added some explanation. Let me know if you have questions.